# Is it possible to "apply" a grease pencil mask?

Tags: grease-pencil, masking

I would like to commit the changes made by a grease pencil mask to the affected grease pencil layer. The reason this is important is that I have a mask that is getting skewed by an armature animation, and this mask does not need to be preserved for any further editing.

So, rather than having a layer masked by another layer, I would like to commit the effect of that mask to the raw grease pencil data, and be able to remove the mask layer completely (or at least hide it); this would simplify my rigging very much.